# Appending Object to all select classes javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 4 HTML elements with the class GMetrics, I am able to set the values if I call the element by ID but I figured this would be much cleaner to have one function that handles populating all the select fields instead of 4 separate functions for each ID

I have a 2D array with my values stored in it, which I was testing previously using the `document.getelementbyid` which worked fine. Now I'm having an issue where it loops over the inner while loop 4 times (which is the number of the GMetrics class I have on the HTML) but it's only appending it to the last class instead of the first 3.

```
window.onload = function popGMetrics()  {

    var index = 0;

   while (index < metrics.length) {
        var self = document.getElementsByClassName('GMetrics');
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        var classCount = self.length;
        var i = 0;

        opt.innerHTML = metrics[index][0];
        opt.value = metrics[index][1];

        while (i < classCount) {
            self[i].appendChild(opt);
            i++;
        }

        index++;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you create a single `option` *reference* in the outer loop. As such you append that *single element* to each select, which has the effect of moving it between the elements. Hence it only appears in the last `select`, as that's where it was last appended by the loop.

To fix this you instead need to create a new `option` instance within the inner loop, so that a new element is created for each `select`. Try this:

```js
let metrics = [
  ['foo', 'bar'],
  ['fizz', 'buzz']
]

window.onload = function popGMetrics() {
  var index = 0;

  while (index < metrics.length) {
    var self = document.getElementsByClassName('GMetrics');
    var classCount = self.length;
    var i = 0;

    while (i < classCount) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = metrics[index][0];
      opt.value = metrics[index][1];    
      self[i].appendChild(opt);
      i++;
    }

    index++;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="GMetrics"></select>
<select class="GMetrics"></select>
<select class="GMetrics"></select>
<select class="GMetrics"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName('select')` might help you get the get elements you are looking for.

Also be aware you are repopulating `classCount` each iteration of the while. Moving:

`var classCount = document.getElementsByClassName('GMetrics').length`

to before the loop will help keep it at its constant value.

Comment: there are going to multiple different categories of drop downs that will have separate items, so I can't use the select tag unfortunately  @Anselm